# fs.promises não existe

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fs

Estava montando uma aplicação quando me deparei com o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O interessante é que utilizo a mesma função em outra aplicação e funciona normalmente. Gostaria de saber se vocês já se depararam com esse erro e como conseguiram corrigir.

Código:

```
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { join } from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

import AppError from '../../errors/AppError';
import User from '../../models/User';

import uploadConfig from '../../config/upload';

interface Request {
  user_id: string;
  avatarFilename: string;
}

class UpdateUserAvatarService {
  public async execute({ user_id, avatarFilename }: Request): Promise<User> {
    const userRepository = getRepository(User);

    const user = await userRepository.findOne(user_id);

    if (!user) {
      throw new AppError('Only authenticated users can change avatar', 401);
    }

    if (user.avatar) {
      const userAvatarFilePath = join(uploadConfig.directory, user.avatar);
      
      const userAvatarFileExists = await fs.promises.stat(userAvatarFilePath);
  }
}
```

A versão do node que estou utilizando é a **v12.18.1**

Comment: Saulo, tente postar o código completo, e não uma imagem, que talvez assim possamos te ajudar

Comment: Pronto @PatrickPerdigão

Comment: Já tentou `import * as fs from 'fs';`?

Comment: @RafaelTavares  Aqui a [documentação com o promises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

Comment: @LeAndrade Tentei sim, não fuciona

Comment: @SauloLins dei uma pesquisada, experimente importar de `fs/promises`. Aparentemente, vide [Pull Request](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/20504), dependendo da versão do Node você precisa importar de um lugar diferente

Comment: @RafaelTavares a minha versão do node é v12.18.1, o interessante é que eu utilizo essa mesma chamada em um outro projeto, nesse mesmo pc e não está acometido com esse erro, mas vou tentar e trago o feedback

Comment: @RafaelTavares o erro que retornou foi : ```Não é possível localizar o módulo 'fs/promises' ou suas declarações de tipo correspondentes.```

Comment: Usando require funcionou: https://repl.it/repls/UtterUnderstatedQuadrilateral, "funcionou" né, o parâmetro é incorreto, mas o método foi encontrado e executado.

Comment: @SauloLins, poderia também editar a sua resposta anexando o `tsconfig.json`? O TypeScript tem comportamentos bem diferentes dependendo da configuração... Verifique também a versão do Node.js instalada e a do pacote `@types/node` instalado nesse projeto.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Eu verifiquei aqui, e a versão typescript que estava intalada, inclusive a types/node estavam muito antigas, não sei como isso aconteceu, já que inicializei esse projeto ante-ontem, atualizei tudo e voltou a funcionar normalmente Muito obrigado!